# Twitter Bootstrap: XS Layout introduces bordered box

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a webpage based on Twitter Bootstrap. It seems to me that when in the xs layout a table in the container is suddendly surrounded by solid borders which disappear when going back to the sm layout.
Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: More explanation needed

Answer (score 0):

Lowcoupling, Could you please show what you mean?
Try this, You can use `hidden-xs`or `visible-xs` class suitably.